# NestJS: ValidationPipe don't working properly for route @Param

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I'm building a NestJS application and I'm trying to use a `ValidationPipe` to validate my request bodies and query params. My `ValidationPipe` looks like this (some code is omitted for the sake of simplicity):

```
@Injectable()
export class ValidationPipe implements PipeTransform<any> {
  private readonly groups?: string[];
  constructor(groups?: string[]) {
    this.groups = groups;
  }

  async transform(value: any, { metatype }: ArgumentMetadata) {
    if (!metatype || !this.toValidate(metatype)) {
      return value;
    }
    const object = plainToClass(metatype, value);
    const errors = await validate(object, {
      groups: this.groups,
    });
    if (errors.length > 0) {
      const violations: Violation[] = [];
      errors.forEach(error => {
        const firstConstraint = getFirstConstraint(
          Object.keys(error.constraints),
        );
        violations.push(
          mapConstraintToViolation(firstConstraint, error.property),
        );
      });
      throw new BadRequestException(new ValidationFailure(violations));
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

Also, I have a controller method with this signature:

```
  @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
  @Put(':id')
  async update(
    @Param('id', new ValidationPipe()) updateParams: UpdateParams,
    @Body(new ValidationPipe(['update'])) userManagementDto: UserManagementDto,
  ): Promise<UserManagementDto>;
```

The request body validation works fine. My `UserManagementDto` correctly parsed and validated. But the validation of the id param doesn't work properly. The id param is serialized to a plain string (as you can see in the print screen):

[image: Id param transformed into a plain string instead of an instance of UserManagementDto]

The `UpdateParams` class is like this:

```
import { IsUUID } from 'class-validator';

export class UpdateParams {
  @IsUUID()
  id: string;
}
```

And I'm making a `PUT` request this way:

```
PUT /users/f10ac0de-0783-48ad-b9bf-c3ba77f8ed06 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "name": "Bruno Peres",
    "email": "bruno3@domain.com.br" 
}
```

I've based my `ValidationPipe` in the sample provided by the framework documentation.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Replace `@Param('id')` by `@Param()` and add a `@Transform` to your DTO. See the linked answer. Let me know, if this does not solve your problem; I will reopen your question.

Comment: Hi @KimKern, sorry for my late answer. I stayed away from this project for a while. Currently, I'm using the `ParseUUIDPipe` to solve my question. Anyway, thank you very much for your help.